# NSPredicate not returning correct results

Tags: ios, nspredicate

I am trying to search for names using NSPredicate in my Code. The search works but it does not return the appropriate results. When i search for a name e.g "Colin" it returns all the other names in the table or another name like "Mike" but if i enter a random string that does not exist, it returns :"No Result Found". When i type a name in the search bar (e.g Lisa) , i expect it to find the name (Lisa) and return it but it doesn't do that

This is my code:

```
- (void)filterData {

[self.filteredSearch removeAllObjects];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS [cd] %@",  mySearchBar.text];

self.filteredSearch = [[self.name filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

}
```

self.name returns all the names in the table and it gets this from a property list

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"lecturers" ofType:@"plist"];


lecturers= [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

// Allocate key objects from lecturers list
name = [lecturers objectForKey:@"name"];


- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

[self filterData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
// Return the number of rows in the section.
if (tableView == self.tableView) {
    return self.name.count;
}
[self filteredSearch];

return self.filteredSearch.count;
}
```

How can I fix this? I have tried using self MATCHES and other NSPredicate formats but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Are you sure self.name is the array of objects you wish to search?

Comment: "The search works but it does not return the appropriate results" What does _that_ mean? Show what `self.name` is, what result you expect, what result you get.

Comment: @danh yeah it is. i have tried searching for other things. it returns the wrong results but if i search something that does not exist it returns "No Result Found"

Comment: You still have not explained what `self.name` contains and what "wrong answers" you are getting. However I do have one suggestion; use `predicateWithBlock:` instead of `predicateWithFormat:`; it is a lot easier and more powerful.

Comment: @matt self.name contains an array of names stored in a property list. "wrong answers" means when i search for a name in my search bar, it returns a different name or all the names in the array but if the name does not exist it returns "No Result Found". i will try predicateWithBlock. Thank you

Comment: did you check the mySearchBar.text have values ?

Comment: @VineeshTP i checked and mySearechBar.text has values.  if([self.filteredSearch isEqual:self.name])
    {
    NSLog(@"Your message here");
        
    }  else
    {
        NSLog(@"nothing in text");
    }
    
   i tried the code to say if the filtered search exists within the self.name array method, it should display the first message. it returns "nothing in text". so searchText has values but i think it cannot compare it to the ones in the array

Comment: Did you check my answer ? Print the filtered array   NSLog(@"filtered Text : %@",self.filteredSearch); Print in ' textDidChange ' method

Comment: @VineeshTP i printed the NSLog and the filteredSearch. it reads the search text and returns the filtered search to the console window correctly but not on the table

Comment: check your cellForRowAtIndexpath

Comment: @VineeshTP the problem was at the cellForRowAtIndexpath. it's working now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please confirm ' searchText ' have values. print searchtext in console window.

```
- (void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {

self.filteredSearch removeAllObjects];

 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd]%@",  searchText];

self.filteredSearch = [[self.name filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate] mutableCopy];

[self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 return self.filteredSearch.count;
}
```